# No package generated in VSTS build (for ASP.net project), so that release failed, why?

Tags: asp.net, build, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-packaging

I'm using  Microsoft team foundation server 2018's build task to build the Asp.net project and then deploy it to Microsoft Azure Website.

The following MsBuild command should publish the website to a publishing package in the build agent's artifact directory:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" 
"C:\agent\_work\8\s\Altoro.sln" /nologo /nr:false /dl:CentralLogger,"C:\agent\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.119.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=9ac05cfe-e8e9-42b6-a469-24e84f79ebe9|SolutionDir=C:\agent\_work\8\s"*ForwardingLogger,"C:\agent\_work\_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.119.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" 
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true 
/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="C:\agent\_work\8\a\\" 
/p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="release" /p:VisualStudioVersion="15.0" 
/p:_MSDeployUserAgent="TFS_2386aba1-5b25-4025-ba06-4677ece9a429_build_8_125"
```

The build succeeded, however, there is no package generated, so the next release job failed with

> '2017-12-02T07:36:56.2618898Z ##[warning]Folder “C:\agent_work\8\a”is empty。no content will be added to drop folder。

Comment: Please take a little time when posting to make the post readable. StackOverflow supports MarkDown. Check the edit I made, it's a lot easier to the eyes than before. Welcome to the community! And please read the guidance for good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What's the project type Web application or website project etc? And can you show the detail build logs here? Is it possible to share a example project which has the same build error in one drive?

Comment: thanks Marina, It is a ASP.Net project. I will just add you to my VSTS account so that you can check it online.  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build ASP.NET website project, you should build `*.publishproj` instead of `*.sln` in Visual Studio build task

In your build definition -> unlink `**\*.sln` for Visual Studio build task -> specify the path to `*.publishproj` file -> save and build again.

[image]

Comment: I tried it on my environment, it doesn't work. and It confused me why the solution file doesn't work? you can test it on my environment.thanks.

Comment: If you are using the `$(BuildPlatform)` and `$(BuildConfiguration)` in VS build task, you must make sure the two variables exist in your VSTS build definition.

Comment: still some confused, anyway, it is solved after adding $(BuildPlatform) and $(BuildConfiguration) to the build definition.   thanks. I will double check the environment later.