# Issue related to ASP.NET Website deployment using VSTS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I created a ASP.NET Website and pushed the entire code on TFS. But when i create a Build Definition in VSTS i do not see any template for the **Website**, all the templates are for **ASP.NET Web application**. The list of templates are shown in the below screenshot:

**Screenshot**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5IOa.png

So if i want to build a website in VSTS do I need to first convert it into the Web Application or is there a third party template available to build my Website in VSTS ?

**Edited:** The website project structure is show below:
[image]

I have given the path till my project file in the Build Solution task as follows:

[image]

The build is successful but i get the message that nothing can be added in the Artifact as shown in the below screenshot:

[image]

**Edited (Latest):** When I create a new "**Website**" in VS 2017 i do not get a project file, only a .sln file is created, so for this website what template and its configuration can i use in VSTS or how can i create a project file(.csproj) so the whole website can come under that project file. The project structure is shown in below screenshot:

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To build website project, you can also use **ASP.NET build process template**.

The only difference is you should specify `**\*.publishproj` instead of `**\*.sln` in VS Build task.

[image]

You can also refer [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605806/no-package-generated-in-vsts-build-for-asp-net-project-so-that-release-failed/47645909#47645909) in another post.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. My website does not contain any project file, it only contains a Solution file. I have edited my question and added a screenshot related to structure of my Website Project. Can you please have a look ?

Comment: So how did you create the website without any project? Or can you share it in one drive?

Comment: Really sorry for confusion, I discovered I have a project file inside the CMS folder. Now I will try as you mentioned above to use the **\*.publishproj. Thanks.

Comment: I have received a message "nothing can be added in the Artifact folder". I have edited the question and provided the screenshot. Can you please have a look ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sandy You specified `.csproj` in VS  Build task. Please specify the `.publishproj` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have one more doubt related to building of Website on VSTS. I have edited my question. Can you please have a look? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since the question you initially asked has been solved, you can accept the answer. For the additional questions as you described in "Edited (Latest)", you can create a new post to describe with more details (such as show the detail steps how you create a website only with sln file etc). And it cab also benefit other members to read this question clearly :)